# How to remove all constraints on a table with SMO objects (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, smo, check-constraints

I would like to know if it is possible to remove all constraints on a table with `SMO` objects (SQL Server and C#) ?

In fact, I would like to know what is the equivalent of the following `SQL` query but with `SMO` Objects:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Right now, I'm trying to find the constraint status in the Index Collection but I can't find the Constraints details.

Here is my 'non working' code:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConnectionSmo));
foreach (Database db in server.Databases)
{
    foreach (Table table in db.Tables)
    {
        // Objective: 'ALTER TABLE YourTableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

        // SMO index vs constraint ?
        foreach (Index index in table.Indexes)
        {
            if (index.IndexKeyType = **Constraint??**)
            {
                index.Disable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea if that is possible ?

Comment: I think you need the property [checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.checks?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0#Microsoft_SqlServer_Management_Smo_Table_Checks). You can then iterate through the [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.check?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0). I don't have a lot of experience here though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight with SMO.  At the point where it stops being easy, switch to TSQL.

Something like:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConnectionSmo));
foreach (Database db in server.Databases)
{
    foreach (Table table in db.Tables)
    {
        string sql = $"ALTER TABLE [$(table.Schema)].[$(table.Name)] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";
        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I was just wondering if SMO has an (easy) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the output if the next 3 statements, combined, will tell you how the primary key of my table `test` is constructed:

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
where TABLE_NAME ='test'


select COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
where TABLE_NAME ='test'


select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PK__test__3BD01996C0D6F5D2'
```

The output is:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK__test__3BD01996C0D6F5D2

(1 row affected)

COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                                      CONSTRAINT_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i                                                                                                                                PK__test__3BD01996C0D6F5D2

(1 row affected)

CONSTRAINT_CATALOG                                                                                                               CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA                                                                                                                CONSTRAINT_NAME                                                                                                                  TABLE_CATALOG                                                                                                                    TABLE_SCHEMA                                                                                                                     TABLE_NAME                                                                                                                       CONSTRAINT_TYPE IS_DEFERRABLE INITIALLY_DEFERRED
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------- ------------------
TEST                                                                                                                             dbo                                                                                                                              PK__test__3BD01996C0D6F5D2                                                                                                       TEST                                                                                                                             dbo                                                                                                                              test                                                                                                                             PRIMARY KEY     NO            NO

(1 row affected)
```

The answer to your question: constraint info is query able in MSSQL, therefore it is possible to create a statement to remote this info.

Comment: But, like @HoneyBadger said: `I don't have … here though.`  